# Setting 'required=True' for ModelForms that have been overridden

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Say I have to override a `ModelForm` (in `forms.py`) to set `labels` or `widgets` differently. i.e:

```
class SomeForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(someForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['someVal'].label = ...
            self.fields['someVal'].widget = ...
```

How do I then set `required=True`?

I know I can do this before the `__init__` like so:

```
class SomeForm(ModelForm):
    someVal = CharField(required=True)  # << here
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(someForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['someVal'].label = ...
            self.fields['someVal'].widget = ...
```

But I'm doing some dynamic stuff and I'd like to set the required in the `__init__`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.fields['someVal'].required = True
```

yes, it's just as simple as this :) you have the same attributes available to the Class in your fields dictionary

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the fields in the form. Just use the same field names as in the model:

```
class SomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    field_a = forms.CharField(
        'My new label', max_length=30, required=True)  # << here

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(someForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

*Why this approach?*

I think overriding the fields directly by defining a new field is a good way if you want to override many attributes e.g. `required`, `label`, `widget`